# Initialize references in C++

Tags: c++

If I want a pointer to point to another variable I make it do so by giving the address to the variable with &.

```
int foo = 10;
int *bar = &foo;
```

Now If I follow the same logic as above and instead creates a reference type.

```
int foo = 10;
int &bar = &foo;
```

I would think this should work, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: While I applaud your quest for knowledge, I can't help but think that creating references in this way is completely pointless -- If there's some utility in doing this please correct me.

Comment: Almost as pointless as that comment. I was simply trying to understand the difference between the 2 examples.

Comment: Please don't take offense, as none was intended. I was just hoping to be enlightened about a use case for this that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a pointer and a reference are not the same thing.
You can think of a reference as just meaning "another name for" or "alias".

In other words, `bar` is just another name for `foo` in your example.
When you do `int &bar = foo;`, you want `bar` to be another name for `foo`, you don't want to assign the address of `foo` to `bar`. However, pointers store the address of the object it points at, hence with a pointer you need the address-of operator to get the address of `foo` and assign that to the `bar` pointer.

Comment: How will the compiler interpret it? Will the operations actually be done on foo, i.e. bar will be replaced with foo, or will bar act as a pointer to foo?

Comment: @user1047423: It is implementation defined. The C++ standard says that it is unspecified whether references have storage or not. In other words, compiler writers are free to do what they want. Generally, pointers are used, but an implementation might remove all bars and just use foo also.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is

```
int &bar = foo;
```

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Comment: The compiler internally makes `bar` point to `foo` and that happens behind the scenes. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @badmaash: The compiler may take every place that says `bar` and replace that with `foo` and not use pointers.

Comment: @Jesse, yes, quite possible. Any such compiler you know that implements this technique?

Comment: @bamaash: As an optimization technique, most compilers will access `foo` directly in certain situations (when it is a local variable for example) rather than storing it's address. However, the same thing may happen if you use pointers also.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because a reference needs to be initialized with the same type that it's a reference to. In this case:

```
int foo = 10;
int &bar = foo;
```

When you try to initialize it this way:

```
int &bar = &foo;
```

You're trying to initialize an int reference with a pointer-to-int. The types don't match.

A reference is not the same as a pointer, although the compiler may implement it as a pointer under the hood. A reference basically says "when I mention bar, I'm really talking about foo".